# Sort 9 train cars on 3 paths

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

On the three paths of a station are A, B, and C types of train cars as shown in the figure.

[image]

A locomotive driver (L) can attach from 1 to 9 train cars to a locomotive at any time, move them to the right path, and then return them to any left path.

For example, if the locomotive picks up 2 train cars from track no. 3 to track no. 1, then after such an action, the distribution of train cars along the tracks will be as follows:

1. А C B А C
2. B C А
3. B

We code these actions by one line as:
**2 3 1**

**Question 1.**

It is necessary to develop an algorithm for the driver's actions to sort train cars. On each path, the train cars the same type should be (it doesn’t matter which path).

**Question 2.**
It is necessary to show that your solution is the shortest.

Source: [vos.olimpiada.ru](http://vos.olimpiada.ru)/ (in Russian).

Comment: old but good question :)

Comment: They are probably not trains, but train cars.

Comment: Cool problem! I would be interested to solve a larger case of this. Reminds me of towers of Hanoi.

Comment: I saw a similar android game where the user have to sort coloured pea or balls into test tubes.

Comment: I couldnt get the 123 notation

Comment: @AlwaysConfused If the tracks were ♥ / ♦ / ♣ instead of 1 / 2 / 3, then "♦3♥" (231) would mean "move 3 carriages from track ♦ to track ♥".  The first and last numbers are which track, and the middle number is how many carriages.

Comment: @Chronocidal Thank you so much it was very difficult to me.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98975/based-on-9-trains-puzzle :)

Comment: @Chronocidal, I think the first number in the notation is the number of carriages. Not the second one. So 231 means move **2** cars from track **3** to track **1**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an optimal solution:

> 7 moves:
>  213, 121, 431, 113, 223, 132, 212

Or in full:

> ```
>  acb
>  bca
>  bac
>  
>  a
>  bca
>  baccb
>  
>  aa
>  bc
>  baccb
>  
>  aaaccb
>  bc
>  b
>  
>  aaacc
>  bc
>  bb
>  
>  aaacc
>  
>  bbbc
>  
>  aaacc
>  c
>  bbb
>  
>  aaa
>  ccc
>  bbb
> ```

Proof of optimality:

> There are 6 pairs of adjacent carriages of mismatched types. Each move can break up at most one such adjacent pair by moving away the right carriage to another track. The left-most carriages of the tracks are not all different types - there are two Bs - so at least one of the left-most carriages will have to move as well. Therefore at least 7 moves are necessary. This solution uses 7 moves, so cannot be made shorter.

Comment: Could you please explain how many 7 moves solutions can be?

Comment: @Nick: There are a lot of them. I did a computer search, and it says there are 562, of which 179 end as aaa/bbb/ccc and 383 as aaa/ccc/bbb.

Answer (score 3):

I reached to a 9-step (8 moves) solution 
it is as follows:

GIF animated version

> [image: RailGIF]

Still-image version:

> 1.   [image: 1] 
>  2.   [image: 2]
>  3.   [image: 3]
>  4.   [image: 4]
>  5.   [image: 5] 
>  6.   [image: 6] 
>  7.   [image: 7] 
>  8.   [image: 8] 
>  9.   [image: 9]

(although I could not understand the 123 notation; sorry about it)